# What's that red-plus icon near a text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

It sometimes appears in Illustrator CS6, only with some text:

[image]

It's annoying me. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shows the text is longer than the text frame area. You have two possibilities:

1. Increase the frame size to see the hidden text and delete it to make the red icon disappear
2. Link the frame to another one clicking the red cross icon and click to another place in the document or another text frame

Answer (score 6):

This means that the text exceeded the size of the container. You need to make the container larger so that all the text fit in it, or link it to another text container (click on the red square and then on another text frame).